# Issue in parsing iWorksDocument with Apache Tika

Tags: java, lucene, apache-tika, text-extraction

I was trying to parse ***iWorksDoc*** with ***Apache Tika***. But am not getting parsed content as it is instead getting some other output from the content handler. 
Code snippet that I've used and the output I got is added below.

```
    private void parseFile(File file) {
    try{
        File file = new File("/home/user/tika/samples/budget.numbers");
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        BodyContentHandler bodyHandler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);
        Parser parser=new AutoDetectParser();
        parser.parse(inputStream, bodyHandler, new Metadata(), context);
        System.out.println("Contents of the file :"+bodyHandler.toString());
        }
        catch(IOException | SAXException | TikaException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Output :-

```
Contents of the file :
Index/Document.iwa
Index/ViewState.iwa
Index/CalculationEngine.iwa
Index/Tables/HeaderStorageBucket-2.iwa
Index/Tables/Tile.iwa
Index/Metadata.iwa
Metadata/Properties.plist
```

I'm able to detect the file type using Detector api correctly. But am not getting the useful content out of the document. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tika should be able to parse Numbers docs. If you're able to share the document, please post it to our [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/tika/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel).  As I look at the parser, we could handle namespaces a bit more robustly, and that *could* be the problem, but I can't tell without the doc.

Comment: The doc was made with the latest version of ios. Will that may be a problem ? I've checked with older version docs and it works. Is it a version compatibility problem ?

Comment: And how to handle the namespaces robustly ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: It looks like we're relying on literal mapping of uri namespaces to "sf" or "sl" for example in our handling of the qName.  For example, "sf:page-start".equals(qName) ... this is all Tika internals, though.  Are you able to share a failing document?  Thank you!

Comment: Created jira issue and attached files :-  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1966

Comment: Thank you. This will require some work, but this is a really important find.

Comment: Y.  Will do.  Thank you, again for raising this.